# How to adjust Grid Cells size to fill max size in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a Grid Layout with cells that fill entire space (without scrolling). Size of cells should adjust depending on device screen size. Size of each cell should be the same.
Now width is fine, but I can't set desired height.
[image: Result of my code]

```
   LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1.0f, true)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(items = myItems, key = { it.name }) { item ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text(text = "test")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a LazyVerticalGrid if you don't want scrolling?

Comment: I wanted to achieve a Grid layout, and a layout without 'lazy' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Set the aspect ratio of the Box to be 1:1, and make the height of the Box equal to its width.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1.0f, true)
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .padding(top = 16.dp),
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(items = myItems, key = { it.name }) { item ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Text(text = "test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. Now height is too tall and cell's doesnt fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can always calculate the item height based on the available space.

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    val padding = PaddingValues(top = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
    val space = 8.dp
    val columnCount = 2
    val rowCount = myItems.size / columnCount + if (myItems.size % columnCount > 0) 1 else 0
    val gridHeight = maxHeight - padding.calculateTopPadding() - padding.calculateBottomPadding()
    val itemHeight = (gridHeight - space * (rowCount - 1)) / rowCount
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .padding(padding),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(columnCount),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space)
    ) {
        items(items = myItems) { item ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .requiredHeight(itemHeight)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text(text = "test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```